# Publish Web Site all of a sudden no longer working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, publish

Out of nowhere the "Publish Web Site" option in Visual Studio isn't doing anything for a particular project. It still compiles the site (no errors), but it never copies the output to the destination directory. I've tried changing the destination to a number of locations, and it creates the new folder, but never copies the output. I tried other projects and they seem to work fine. What would stop one project from copying the output?

**Update**: This is a web site project, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem was with the "Allow this precompiled site to be updateable" option. This was turned off at some point and was causing the problem. Turning it back on caused the files to be copied again. Why should this make a difference? Is there another setting somewhere that needs to work in conjunction with this setting?